# Where can I find the TLE of ExseedSat 1, India's first ever private LEO satellite?

Tags: spacex, artificial-satellite, low-earth-orbit, tracking, spaceflight-firsts

On 3rd December 2018, a private Indian company [Exseed Space](https://www.exseedspace.com/exseed-sat-1) launched it's first ever satellite into space called *ExseedSat 1*. But I couldn't find the TLE for this satellite. I looked it up on n2yo website to find nothing.

It was carried as a [payload on SpaceX's Falcon 9](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau_det/falcon-9_v1-2_b5.htm) listed under 3rd December 2018. I could find TLE's of some of the payload satellites from that launch on n2yo but not ExseedSat 1.

Can anyone help me find it's TLE?

Comment: I've just asked [Any reception reports from ExseedSAT1 yet?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/12661/8643)

Comment: I've just asked [What is “OBJECT BS”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33860/12102) I sure hope that's not it! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Unofficial
From https://planet4589.org/space/log/launchlogy.txt

```
2018-099T      Vusat-OSCAR-96                 Exseedsat-1               S43775
```

Otherwise known as OBJECT T, or number 43775.

As I found this, I checked N2YO, and saw there was a 70-degree elevation pass **currently** over my QTH, listened on only radio available (145.9 MHz FM), and heard nothing.

Comment: `+1` Very nice, well done! Though unofficial, it's certainly a [reputable source](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/11467/jonathan-mcdowell).

Comment: just fyi there are currently 14 questions tagged with [amateur-radio](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amateur-radio).

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer because it looks like the identities of all of these haven't been worked out and published yet.

Gunter's Space Page for ExseedSat-1 is https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/exseedsat-1.htm

From there we can only see part of the Cospar ID `2018-099` without the letters. This list http://www.dk3wn.info/p/?page_id=29535 still says "tbd" and nothing here definitive yet https://community.libre.space/t/new-satellites-plan-for-sso-a-smallsat-express-launch-on-november-19/2825

Going to Celestrak SatCat Search https://celestrak.org/satcat/search.php and then clicking Raw SATCAT Data gives a giant list with 65 lines that begin with `2018-099` from `2018-099A` to `2018-099BS`. Most don't have names assigned yet.

It takes a while. You can read the following to get an idea:

- [ISRO's PSLV-C37 with 104 satellites - after 56 hours only six TLEs, which factor is greatest challenge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20191/12102)
- [It's been over two weeks now, will the real Humanity Star please stand up?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24656/12102)
- [What are the things that can be done in future mass-cubesat deploys to make them less irksome to orbital space debris experts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32182/12102)

---

While we're waiting, I'll add the SatCat listing for 25-Dec-2018 about 15:00 UTC, alphabetized by name:

```
AL-FARABI 2       2018-099AZ   43805  *+ 
BLACKSKY GLOBAL 2 2018-099BG   43812  *+ 
CORVUS-BC 4       2018-099K    43767  *+ 
CSIM-FD           2018-099AM   43793  *+ 
EAGLET-I          2018-099AJ   43790  *+ 
ESEO              2018-099AL   43792  *+ 
FLOCK 3S-1        2018-099M    43769  *+ 
FLOCK 3S-2        2018-099BR   43821  *+ 
FLOCK 3S-3        2018-099AG   43788  *+ 
HAWK-A            2018-099H    43765  *+ 
HAWK-B            2018-099AN   43794  *+ 
HAWK-C            2018-099AT   43799  *+ 
ICEYE X2          2018-099D    43761  *+ 
ITASAT 1          2018-099AE   43786  *+ 
MOVE II           2018-099Y    43780  *+ 
NEXTSAT-1         2018-099BF   43811  *+ 
OBJECT A          2018-099A    43758  *+ 
OBJECT AB         2018-099AB   43783  *+ 
OBJECT AC         2018-099AC   43784  *+ 
OBJECT AD         2018-099AD   43785  *+ 
OBJECT AF         2018-099AF   43787  *+ 
OBJECT AH         2018-099AH   43789  *+ 
OBJECT AK         2018-099AK   43791  *+ 
OBJECT AP         2018-099AP   43795  *+ 
OBJECT AQ         2018-099AQ   43796  *+ 
OBJECT AS         2018-099AS   43798  *+ 
OBJECT AU         2018-099AU   43800  *+ 
OBJECT AV         2018-099AV   43801  *+ 
OBJECT AX         2018-099AX   43803  *+ 
OBJECT B          2018-099B    43759  *+ 
OBJECT BA         2018-099BA   43806  *+ 
OBJECT BB         2018-099BB   43807  *+ 
OBJECT BC         2018-099BC   43808  *+ 
OBJECT BD         2018-099BD   43809  *+ 
OBJECT BE         2018-099BE   43810  *+ 
OBJECT BH         2018-099BH   43813  *+ 
OBJECT BK         2018-099BK   43815  *+ 
OBJECT BL         2018-099BL   43816  *+ 
OBJECT BM         2018-099BM   43817  *+ 
OBJECT BN         2018-099BN   43818  *+ 
OBJECT BP         2018-099BP   43819  *+ 
OBJECT BQ         2018-099BQ   43820  *+ 
OBJECT BS         2018-099BS   43822     
OBJECT C          2018-099C    43760  *+ 
OBJECT F          2018-099F    43763  *+ 
OBJECT G          2018-099G    43764  *+ 
OBJECT J          2018-099J    43766  *+ 
OBJECT L          2018-099L    43768  *+ 
OBJECT N          2018-099N    43770  *+ 
OBJECT P          2018-099P    43771  *+ 
OBJECT S          2018-099S    43774  *+ 
OBJECT T          2018-099T    43775  *+ 
OBJECT U          2018-099U    43776  *+ 
OBJECT V          2018-099V    43777  *+ 
OBJECT W          2018-099W    43778  *+ 
OBJECT X          2018-099X    43779  *+ 
OBJECT Z          2018-099Z    43781  *+ 
PW-SAT2           2018-099BJ   43814  *+ 
RANGE-A           2018-099Q    43772  *+ 
RANGE-B           2018-099R    43773  *+ 
SKYSAT-C12        2018-099AR   43797  *+ 
SKYSAT-C13        2018-099AW   43802  *+ 
SNUSAT-2          2018-099AA   43782  *+ 
STPSAT-5          2018-099E    43762  *+ 
SUOMI-100         2018-099AY   43804  *+
```