# How do cubesat owners first find out their cubesat's initial trajectory? How do they point antennas at it before official TLEs start to appear?

Tags: launch, cubesat, two-line-elements, payload-deployment, state-propagation

When cubesats are first deployed it can sometimes take several days before they start appearing in official TLE distributions, and even then if many were deployed it may take a lot more work to decide which one is which.

- [ISRO's PSLV-C37 with 104 satellites - after 56 hours only six TLEs, which factor is greatest challenge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20191/12102)
- [It's been over two weeks now, will the real Humanity Star please stand up?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24656/12102)
- [What is "OBJECT BS"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33860/12102)
- [Where can I find the TLE of ExseedSat 1, India's first ever private LEO satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33031/12102)
- [What can be done in future mass-cubesat deploys to make them "less irksome" to orbital space debris experts?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32182/12102)
- [Do deployments of multiple cubesats obey proposed guidelines such as 20 seconds or more between deployments at 5 m/s or faster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45029/12102)
- [CubeSat Orbit Determination](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19592/12102)

**Other Problems keeping track of satellites:**

- [How are military satellites with (apparently) classified TLEs still showing up on sat map websites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18300/12102)
- [Has NORAD ever experienced a catastrophic event and "lost track of" a bunch of objects?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26600/12102)
- [Are SpaceBEEs actually hard to track?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25978/12102)

As far as I know, cubesats don't (yet) have digital license plates that can be read from the ground (easily). So in some cases it may be necessary to exchange some data before some TLE's can be associated with a specific satellite name. One way to establish that is to make radio contact with a given cubesat.

There may be other operational reasons as well for why you might want to start trying to talk to your cubesat as soon as possible.

**Question:** How do cubesat owners first find out their cubesat's initial trajectory? How do they point antennas at it before official TLEs start to appear? Do the launch providers share any trajectory informaion? If so, what is the format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, there isn't currently a good solution for this, especially for amateurs, hobbyists, or small commercial operators. These groups often fly small satellites on rideshare missions. For smallsat rideshare, there are a so many uncertainties that removing tracking uncertainty is really important

## Uncertainties

- Is my satellite dead-on-arrival (DOA)?
- If my satellite isn't DOA, is it surviving in space?
- Did my antennas deploy?
- Is my spacecraft communications system functioning properly on orbit?
- Is my ground station functioning properly at my spacecraft's frequency?
- Is my link closing? Directly overhead? At the horizon?
- **Where is my satellite? Which of the satellites deployed from the rideshare is mine?**

On the last point, I first thought the official TLEs would be organized in deployment order, but they aren't. While the mass is definitely known, the drag coefficient probably isn't, and the density of the atmosphere the satellite flies through at the correct point in time definitely isn't well characterized. As a result, the order of the satellites in orbit may not match the order of deployment.

## Satellite Tracking

With so many uncertainties, reducing the uncertainty around satellite tracking is really important, especially for rideshare missions. The best way to do that, is to begin attempting communications immediately after launch, when the satellites are still relatively close together. That way, you can point to one and be fairly confident that you're pointing to all of them. As days pass, the satellites separate and the total search area becomes unmanageable.

I've been involved in two separate CubeSat launches so far and both times we have been given state vectors after launch. I was loosely involved in the [BYU PICs](https://spacecraft.byu.edu/pics) launch operations (I had graduated and left the team before) and my company, [Care Weather](https://www.careweather.com), recently launched it's first satellite, [Hatchling Veery](https://www.careweather.com/all_missions). I'll include a few examples at the end of this post. Both times, immediately after launch, we manufactured TLEs. Both times, our TLEs had errors due to inane complexities in the definitions of the coordinate systems or epochs used.

Everyone I know involved in satellite communications produces TLEs from state vectors between launch and issuance of official TLEs. On the ELaNa XX mission with Virgin Orbit, we had an extensive email chain as people tried to iron out issues with their TLE calculation and [the SatNogs forum was sharing manufactured TLEs for early tracking as well](https://community.libre.space/t/virgin-orbit-launcherone-elana-20-2021-01-17/7141/12).

There is a lot of wasted effort and inefficient collaboration at this point in the process and it contributes to space debris by resulting in some satellites to never be identified. The BYU team actually had confirmation that PIC-A and/or PIC-B was not DOA as the satellites' camera flash was seen by the rocket camera. However, the PICs team dealt with all of these uncertainties (and more) and was unable to make contact in the early stage. They are still trying to make contact, but more than half of the ELaNa XX satellites were never identified, so there's like only a 25% chance that they're looking in the right spot. Combine that with most passes being low to the horizon and the chance of contact being made now, even if the satellites are still operational, is slim.

## Potential Solutions

- Develop an open-source TLE generator that strictly outputs [standard markers for denoting that the TLEs are unnofficial](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26117/how-to-generate-tle-file/26124?noredirect=1#comment104785_26124).
- Upgrade gpredict to propagate state vectors.

## State Vectors

Here are a couple examples of state vectors as given by the the launch provider on each mission. There is no standard on state vector contents, so some were easier to work with than others, but some aspect of the delivery created headache for TLE generation on both missions.

### Virgin Orbit ELaNa XX

[The polar cube team shared their state vectors on the SatNogs forum](https://community.libre.space/t/virgin-orbit-launcherone-elana-20-2021-01-17/7141/13) right after deployment.

### Rocket Lab "They Go Up So Fast"

Rocket Lab gave us their official TLEs shortly after deployment. They had given us predicted state vectors and a trajectory analysis document long before the launch.

[image: State Vectors delivered by RocketLab to Care Weather]

Comment: `+1` Thanks for your answer! It's great to have a first-hand account to complement the more speculative "oh it's easy" answers. :-) It's also very illuminating to see how different launch providers vary so much in what they provide.

Answer (score 7):

A cubesat without a propulsion system deployed from the second stage of the rocket using weak mechanical forces only just follows the trajectory of the second stage. Differences between the trajectories of the deployed cubesats and the second stage are very small.

So the cubesat owners may use the latest trajectory information from the launcher as initial trajectory of their cubesat before official TLEs start to appear.

A diagramm from [EXOLAUNCH](https://exolaunch.com/products.html) about the [EXOpod](https://exolaunch.com/user_guides/EXOpod_User_Guide.pdf) cubesat deployer.

[image]

From the [CarboNix User Guide](https://exolaunch.com/user_guides/CarboNIX_User_Guide.pdf) page 19:

[image]

The tolerance of the spring energy of 25 % results in a speed error of about 12 %. For a separation speed of about 1.5 m/s this error is 0.17 m/s, the error after one 90 minutes orbit will be 0.92 km. Over a distance of 1000 km this will be a direction error of only 3.2 arcminutes.

As David Hammen commented, the deployment vector is not random, the cubesat launcher is responsible for direction and speed of deployment. The actual deployment speed of the cubesat depends on its mass, but the mass of the cubesat is precisely known.

Comment: "How do they point antennas at it before official TLEs start to appear?" Disagree. If it is deployed at 1 meter per second, then 24 hours later it could be as far as 85 km away. If it is 400 km altitude and you are pointing a directional antenna, then you are off by 11°. If its 2 m/s then it's as much as 22° per day offset. [Recommendations](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45029/12102) say 5 m/s. When you only have a minute or two of visibility, it's really hard to search.

Comment: That is correct. Note that operators also provide the ground stations with a tracking profile and a scanning pattern for the antenna in case the spacecraft isn't where they expect it to be. Moreover, that technique is also used for cubesats with propulsion: operators will compute a navigation solution and locate the spacecraft before turning on the thrusters.

Comment: @ChrisR which ground stations *available to cubesat owners* actually provide scanning patterns for them? Is this really true? Wouldn't passes over any given ground station be rare in the first few days, and all the cubesats be passing over at roughly the same time? Sounds like a very unlikely scenario to me.

Comment: Depends on the Cubesat I guess. The DSN is used for CAPSTONE ;-)

Comment: @ChrisR are the DSN dishes operated in "LEO search mode" very often? Those tiny FOVs and slow slew rates must make that quite a challenge!

Comment: `-1` because 1) this is pure speculation, there is nothing here about what information launch providers actually supply. 2) even if possible to derive, the relative velocity is useless until an accurate TLE for the 2nd stage is provided. Can you add some facts as to when that actually happens? 3) In order to to use a deploy velocity, you need to know its direction. Even 1 m/s means in 24 hours it can be as much as 30 seconds ahead or behind the 2nd stage (retrograde/prograde deploy), and they usually deploy backwards/forwards on purpose to maximize spreading out to make early tracking easier.

Comment: This stuff about "arc minutes" is at a minimum misleading. It's *tens of degrees per day* at 1 m/s.

Comment: @uhoh The diagram from EXOLAUNCH is pure speculation? The small difference between the second stage's trajectory and the cubesat's trajectory is speculation?

Comment: @Uwe this is a "it could be possible" answer. I've asked "How **do** cubesat owners...?" How **do** they...?" You've speculated how they **could**, or how they **might**, and answered "Would it be possible...?" If you can provide actual examples of cubesat owners pointing their antennas and communicating before the cubesat has a TLE, then that would be an answer.

Comment: @uhoh - I disagree with your disagreement for two reasons. One is that the deployment is not random. It is performed in a fairly well known direction and with a fairly well known magnitude.The fairly well known deployment time and deployment mechanism behavior combined with the second stage's fairly well known orbit provides the ability to predict an expected state. There is an uncertainty in this, and that is what Uwe wrote about.

Comment: The second reason is that the cubesat operator will start looking for the cubesat shortly after it first appears above the horizon rather than when it is directly overhead. The angular difference is much smaller at that much larger distance and mostly manifests itself in an error in acquisition time. Once locked on, a tracking antenna will follow where the satellite is rather than where it is predicted to be.

Comment: @DavidHammen I see, so the whole "spacecraft cluster" begins its pass low on the horizon at 3 to 5x of the minimum range. As long as you have the gain you may be able to pick up enough signal to confirm identity. Then if your "cubesat ground station" has some kind of conical scanning or some other algorithm that works well, then it is possible to continue to track. So my question is worded to ask for what actually happens, not what could happen. Is it possible to cite an example of this actually happening? Ground station needs to have a pass before the spacecraft gets a TLE to be a good answer

Comment: @DavidHammen re 'well known, not random', I didn't say it's random. But the launch provider *has to tell you* which direction, how fast, etc. My question asks about this. Do they tell you this information? If so how? When? By phone? Email? I've asked for what actually happens, not what could or might happen theoretically or in principle.

Comment: @uhoh, trying to get back on track here: "But the launch provider has to tell you which direction, how fast, etc. " Yes, and that's communicated. There are months of exchanges by email or file transfers between the launch team and the operator teams. Models are matches, error margins assessed by their impact on the mission, etc. And thank goodness, otherwise, we'd be launching things with a huge uncertainty. Many missions also require that the separation happens in visibility of their ground stations with the station tracking the vehicle to ensure a quick navigation solution.

Comment: @ChrisR is all this top secret, privileged and "eyes only", or is it possible to find some blog or story or something citable where we can read about it?

Comment: One source is the "DSN Mission Service Interfaces, Policies, and Practices (MSIPP)" PDF document which lists all of the practices and interfaces between the DSN and operators: https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/files/875-0001-G1.pdf . For other ground stations, such as SSC, best is to contact them directly: https://sscspace.com/ssc-worldwide/ground-station-network/ .

Comment: @uhoh What do you miss? Information from other cubesat launchers?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121273/discussion-on-answer-by-uwe-how-do-cubesat-owners-first-find-out-their-cubesats).

Comment: This answer is speculative and doesn't match up with my experience.

Answer (score 6):

I've done this before, on the latest Falcon Heavy launch. Although the satellites we were working with were a good bit larger than most cubesats.

Essentially, the launch provider gives you state vectors, and then someone in the chain needs the STK ODTK to turn the state vectors into TLEs. Unfortunately I think the license for that is around $60k. I would be very interested in an open source solution to do the same thing, as ground systems almost always take as input TLEs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One way to get things started on that would be to post a question, something like "What are the challenges to writing an open source LEO state vector to TLE converter?" Asking it this way will cover all types of challenges, informational, mathematical, regulatory (if any) etc.

Comment: Your question [How to generate TLEs based on a set of observation points (location, azimuth, elevation… no range)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54246/12102) is somewhat a superset but a poor one, as answers will require both converting a short span of ground observations (60 seconds) to a state vector and then conversion of a low accuracy state vector to an inevitably low quality TLE. Here you are given much, much more accurate state vectors so the challenge for the TLE converter is much larger.

Answer (score 3):

The launch provider provides the state vectors, based on the deployment force, angle, and the state vector of the rocket stage when the cubesat was deployed. The exact format may vary, it could be a TLE or a state vector or something like that, in any case it will be something both the provider and the customer will agree on well in advance.

Comment: is there some way this can be established as true based on sources? Does this come from personal experience? Is there some blogpost or article or mention of this somewhere?

Comment: This is from personal experience. I can't speak to all providers, but I do know the ones that I have worked from this is the case.

Comment: When a cubesat customer plans the mission carefully, he has to deal with communication to the cubesat immediately after deployment. So he has to think about the state vectors of the cubesat provided by the launcher and the exchange format. Of course the uncertainity of the state vectors should be considered.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Have you received a TLE from a launch provider before? I haven't seen a launch provider do that. It would save a lot of headache in working with gpredict.

Comment: A company I worked with in the past received equivalent information from the launch provider. I didn't personally look at it, but I was aware that it was received. Can't say a lot more than that really, but...