# Has the Humanity Star been spotted yet?

Tags: observation, visibility-of-spacecraft, humanitystar

With all the hullabaloo that the Roadster/Spaceman duo has been getting, is there any indication that the [Humanity Star](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24616/12102) has been seen visually yet?

Any reports of it's sparkly mirrorball-like qualities?

Of course we know it's been seen by radar and/or satellite tracking telescopes, since it continues to be issued updated TLEs regularly. But what about naked eye visible sightings?

**edit 1:** As explained by [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24625/12102) visibility has been poor from North American and this will soon change, but there are people nearly everywhere, and the Humanity Star has been designed to be bright and pulsing and therefore particularly noticeable.

**edit 2:** [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oL8O2Cfc2P4) isn't it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.satobs.org/seesat/Jan-2018/0201.html), Humanity Star was spotted at "0106 on [January] the 27th New
Zealand time (1206 on the 26th UTC.)" The sighting was made from Pukehina, Bay of Plenty, New Zealand.

It was observed [again](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9rS8efs_Uk) on February 25th at 9:29 NZT, and it definitely looks very "disco-flashy" on the video, in my opinion.

Comment: That's excellent, blinky and all!