# Attitude of the upcoming "Orbital Reflector"; will it result in good visibility?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, cubesat, space-art, visibility-of-spacecraft

There's a new (passive solar) *orbital reflector*, called the Orbital Reflector.

While Mayak (Маяк) was a crowdfunded project at Moscow State Mechanical Engineering University and the Humanity Star was designed and built by a small group at Rocket Labs, the Orbital Reflector project, driven by artist Trevor Paglen has backing and technical contribution from spacecraft engineers and aerospace companies, the [Nevada Museum of Art](https://www.nevadaart.org/), and (likely) other patrons.

Looking at the project's website [orbitalreflector.com](https://www.orbitalreflector.com/) I can see that the inflatable structure is long and skinny and the orientations of the faces are not distributed uniformly.

I would guess that some substantial thought has been put into the project. What will be the orientation of the spacecraft and it's reflectors once in LEO, and will that orientation be good or bad for visibility?

**Question:** What will be the attitude of the upcoming "Orbital Reflector"? Will this result in good visibility?

See the artist's (Paglen's) own article in Medium: [Let’s Get Pissed Off About Orbital Reflector…](https://medium.com/@trevor.paglen_21030/lets-get-pissed-off-about-orbital-reflector-44ef70feb9bc) and Gizmodo's [Hey Artists, Stop Putting Shiny Crap Into Space](https://gizmodo.com/hey-artists-stop-putting-shiny-crap-into-space-1828299936)

[image: the Orbital Reflector spacecraft]

---

If you would like to read further about these previous orbital reflectors, the questions and answers contain plenty of reference material:

- [Mayak, a magnitude -10 (minus ten) satellite; how is the large, delicate reflector expanded?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22476/12102)
- [Two week mark; has Mayak (Маяк) been spotted yet? Reflector deployed? Astronomy “ruined”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22311/12102)
- [Does Humanity Star have non-reflective triangular panels? If so, what are their characteristics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24616/12102)
- [Why would Humanity Star not be visible from North America (USA?) until March?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24622/12102)
- [Has the Humanity Star been spotted yet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25416/12102)
- [What is the name of the polyhedral shape of the Humanity Star?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2620066/284619)

Comment: Just to check, "Will this result in good visibility?" refers to the visibility from the ground for us Earthlings, correct?

Comment: @ChrisR Check the several links I've taken the time to read and then include, two by the artist and one (Gizmodo) about.

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but both the image and youtube "thumbnail" show solar panels facing away from the sun, so I'd question your guess that "some substantial thought has been put into the project"

Comment: @JCRM well 1) *the project* has several aspects and thought may not have been allocated across all of them evenly, 2) the space artist for the concept drawing may not have been the engineer, 3) the panels might simply be double-sided.

Comment: Hm... I have a follow-up, what's the purpose of this endeavor?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn are you asking *what is the purpose of art?* or *what do the first three links in the question say?*

Comment: @uhoh none make mention of a scientific objective, so I suppose the former.